# Google Form from Facebook Group

Tags: google-forms, facebook-groups

I have a a google form that I would like to only make available to members of a closed facebook group. The form is anonymous and members are free to use it as often as they would like. The problem is that occasionally we have members abuse this anonymous posting feature and even with moderation it causes strife within the group. Since the google form is just a link, removed members still post things by saving the link. Changing the link occasionally works, but members will continue to use the old link and we will miss posts.

I am looking into some options on how to implement this:

1. Have a daily password in the group that users must submit in the form.

   - This would probably work, but many of the members of the group are older and this adds another layer of difficulty to the process
2. <del>Embed a JotForm form in a custom page tab.</del>

   - Page tabs only work for pages, not groups.
3. Some kind of link verification; i.e., the link to the google form only works when accessed from the hyperlink in the group's pinned post.

   - If this is possible, then it would probably work well. I'm not even sure what to search for though.
4. Using a different service other than google forms.

Maybe something else all together. Very open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to add special Short Answer type question in the form with a Validation rule. The validation can be set to a specific word or number (or even a regex validation) and it can be changed on a daily basis.
This is how you could implement the first option you have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options: a regular password on the Google Form (consider usability for older members); embed a form in a secure webpage, share the URL within the group; or try a different service like SurveyMonkey. If abuse persists, consider custom solutions or reevaluate your anonymous posting policy.